# Python Pandas groupby agg or transform on max value_counts to drop duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, drop-duplicates

I have this df, and want to drop duplicates based on the max value counts of 'rating' (its binary field). None of the drop_duplicates with combination of grouby, max, count isn't fecthing the desired output. Any suggestion highly appreciated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Cup','Pack'],
     'rating': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})
```

Desired Output :

| brand | rating |
| --- | --- |
| Yum Yum | 1 |
| Indomie | 0 |
| Cup | 1 |
| Pack | 0 |

tried below but not helping with desired output.

```
df.groupby(["brand",'rating']).max().reset_index()
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand'], keep='last')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rating is binary, you can do `mean` and compare to 0.5:

```
df.groupby('brand', sort=False)['rating'].mean().ge(0.5).astype(int).reset_index()
```

In general, you can use `mode`:

```
df.groupby('brand', sort=False)['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
     brand  rating
0  Yum Yum       1
1  Indomie       0
2      Cup       1
3     Pack       0
```